# Haskell: String parser not recognizing escaped double-quote

Tags: string, haskell, parsec

I have this Parser (exercise from Write a Lisp in 48 hours):

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Monad

data LispVal = String String deriving Show

parseString :: Parser LispVal
parseString = do char '"'
                 x <- many innerChar
                 char '"'
                 return $ String x
              where innerChar = noneOf ['\\','\"'] <|> escapeChar
                    escapeChar = 
                        do char '\\'
                           c <- oneOf ['n', '"', 'r', 't']
                           return $ case c of
                                      '"' -> '\"'
                                      'n' -> '\n'
                                      'r' -> '\r'
                                      't' -> '\t'
```

So, this code seems to work fine for strings with all escaped characters, only when the char is \" it seems to end the String.

- I receive a warning because the pattern match is not exhaustive, what should the general case be?
- The code seems to fail in cases like "some\"string", where it succeeds but returns "some"

Comment: Please make your code self-contained. In particular, add the required imports.

Comment: oh ok, sorry, will do it

Comment: you can ignore the compiler warning or add a case `_ -> undefined` to shut up the compiler (it's fine from a logical standpoint) - aside from this your code works for me just fine `parseTest parseString "\"\\\"hallo\\\"\""` returns the complete *inner* string: `String "\"hallo\""`

Comment: btw: if you write `[ '\\', '\"' ]` it's far more readable (than `"\\\""`) IMO (just as you did for `oneOf`)

Comment: also: your example works too but of course you have to input it as `"\"some\\\"someString\""` into GHCi (yeah you must escape your escapses ;) )

Comment: ohhh, I was testing it wrong then, it was "\"some\"string\""

Comment: thanks you :D, is there a better way to test these strings? I think that in the command line I would probably have to do that as well, right?

Comment: if you get it from stdin? No you would not have to

Comment: yes, ah ok, I will try it

Comment: Note that `'"'` and `'\"'` are equivalent. I'm saying this since you use both in your code.

Comment: oh really?  is that always the same? in the case for 'a' '\a' as well.

Comment: @lhahn `'\"`' and `'"'` are equivalent: the double quote needs not be escaped in a character literal, since the delimiter for character literals is a single quote (as opposed to a double quote for strings). However, `'\a'` (BELL) and `'a'` (lowercase letter A) are *not* equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in this:

```
λ *Main > parseTest parseString $ show "some\"string"
String "some\"string"

λ *Main > show "some\"string"
"\"some\\\"string\""

λ *Main > parseTest parseString "\"some\\\"string\""
String "some\"string"

-- This happened? Escaping is tricky.
λ *Main > parseTest parseString "\"some\"string\""
String "some"
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick with `show`, that makes it a lot easier to test!